# Text translation into French

Tags: translation, language-translation, french

Here is the list of text translation languages.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/business/languages/

Based on this list, I see “French”.
Is there support for translation into Canadian French?  If it’s translation to France French, we can’t use it.  I’m no language expert, but apparently there are differences in grammar, differences in vocabulary, and more.  https://unitedlanguagegroup.com/blog/canadian-french-vs-french-7-important-differences/

It seems that a region subtag is not specified for text translation languages, which is leading to doubt and confusion as to what it actually represents.
Does “French” text translation represent French as used in France, or does it represent French as used in Canada?  Is there support for text translation into Canadian French?  If not, are there plans to support it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It seems the question is very broad.

Answer (score 1):

From Microsoft's POV, French from France and French from Canada are the same.
From the POV of software prompts, and having written bilingual software for 30+ years, I can tell you that it is equivalent.
Much like differences of English between Australia, UK, USA, Canada.

The keyboard layout is different, AZERTY versus QWERTY. Back in the early days of XP, whenever you chose French, here in Quebec is was a hassle typing in a product key on a QWERTY keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I am no language expert either. But believe that there does not exist a service that offers automated translation with nationality variants or dialects.

I would suggest to analyze the actual accuracy that you get using the MS French API and then judge if it is a good fit for your use case.